# unable to execute package control information extraction (dpkg-deb): Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

am facing error if I do any installation with sudo apt install for any package. The error is irrespective of the package. And I am doing the installation with sudo su (root) user. Please advise.

command:

```
sudo apt install consul
```

error details:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  consul
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 241 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/55.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 143 MB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute package control information extraction (dpkg-deb): Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/consul_1.15.3-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/consul_1.15.3-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```